# convert ° (degree) character gg°mm'' ss' data

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, replace, symbols

I need convert coordinate data in a format `gg°mm"ss'` to a decimal format.
I am using `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- #` at the head of the module.

Line of data in original file:

```
    06:58   15:07:26    -53°08'00.7"   -70°51'27.5"   2404.1   746.1   -2.4 22.3    0.3675
```

When the file is processed and eliminated blank spaces and write in other with finder the line is:

```
06:58 15:07:26 -53∞08'00.7" -70∞51'27.5" 2404.1 746.1 -2.4 22.3 0.3765
```

I need convert `-53°08'00.7"` to decimal format `-gg,ddddd`.
But I don't understand because in Spyder is correct but not in finder. Any hints?
This is part of the code:

```
if os.path.exists(name):  
    with open(name, 'r', encoding="utf-8", errors="surrogateescape") as f:  
        for line in itertools.islice(f, 2, None):  # start=2, stop=None  
            if not '//' in line:  
                linea1 = re.sub('[ \t]+' , ' ', line)  
                signo = linea1.find('-',0,6)  
                if signo == -1 :  
                    file_mov.write(linea1)
```

Comment: please add the best effort source code in python that you seem to have used (with in and output) the latter making clear, what is missing to a perfect out put. That would help in helping you IMO.

Comment: What error are you getting? Not sure what `-gg,ddddd` means - what is the exact output you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the following helps. It is not elegant, but it should give you a good idea of what is going on.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

degree_sym = u'\N{DEGREE SIGN}'
sample = u'  06:58   15:07:26    -53\N{DEGREE SIGN}08\'00.7"   -70\N{DEGREE SIGN}51\'27.5"   2404.1   746.1   -2.4 22.3    0.3675'

regex = r'(-?)(\d+)'+ degree_sym + r"(\d+)'" + r'(\d+|\d+\.\d+)"'

converted_words = []

for word in sample.split():
        m = re.match(regex, word, flags=re.UNICODE)
        if m:
                sign    = int(m.groups()[0]+'1')
                degrees = float(m.groups()[1])
                minutes = float(m.groups()[2])/60.0
                seconds = float(m.groups()[3])/3600.0
                result  = "{0:.5f}".format(sign*(degrees+minutes+seconds))
                converted_words.append(result)
        else:
                converted_words.append(word)
answer = " ".join(converted_words)
print(answer)
```

Output:

```
06:58 15:07:26 -53.13353 -70.85764 2404.1 746.1 -2.4 22.3 0.3675
```